# Preserving historical information of the Collatz function?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

In some sense this two equations are the same, namely $f_2$ preserves the historical information of $f_1^n$, where the exponent is function composition, but I am not sure how to show this rigorously. $f_1$ is well known,

$
f_1(s)=
\begin{cases}
 3s+1&\text{if}\, s \in \mathbb{N}_{odd}\\
 \frac{S}{2}&\text{if } s \in \mathbb{N}_{even} \\
\end{cases}
$

$f_2(s)=3s+2^{E(s)}$

where $E(s)=\max(\; b \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}: \;\;2^b|s\;)$, and $$f_1^n(s)=1 \iff (f_2^m(s) \text{ is a power of two for some } m)$$

How do I show $f_1$ and $f_2$ are equivalent in this sense? Any ideas or references would be appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

My argument to move from $f_1$ to $f_2$ is as follows:

Represent the input $s$  in binary form. And consider $f_1^{odd}(s)=3s+1$ and $f_1^{even}(s)=\frac{s}{2}$ for odd and even inputs, respectively.

Applying $f_1^{even}$ repeatedly on the input $s_{even}$ until we obtain an output that is $s_{odd}$ to then use $f_2^{odd}(s)$ amounts to two operations:

1. Finding the first/lowest bit set on $s_{even}$ and adding one bit at that position. This is equivalent to adding $2^{E(s_{even})}$ to $s_{even}$; this will make that bit position become 0.
2. Adding $(s_{even}<<1)$ to the above computation, i.e. shifting by one to left or multiplying by two. Leaving the position where the lowest bit was set on $s_{even}$ intact.

Hence, after doing the two operations above we get, $f_2$. In particular, at all times

$$ popcount(\; f_{odd}(s)  \;) = popcount(\;f_2(s) \;) $$

$$ popcount(\; f^n_{even}(s) : n = \text{ (a power until output is odd)} + 1  \;) = popcount(\;f_2(s) \;) $$

The bits that change after both operation are the same bits modulo the number of trailing zeroes; that is, in $f_2$ they are at an offset.

Hence, when the Collatz function has a one bit output, our function $f_2$ is power of two; as only powers of two have only one bit set in binary.

$
\\
\\
$

**Edit 2:** By convention we use $\mathbb{N}$ to mean natural numbers greater than zero.

Consider the following functions:

\begin{align}
E(s) &= \max(\; r \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \; : \; \; \; 2^r\; | \;s) \\
C(s) &=
\begin{cases}
 3s+1&\text{if}\, s \in \mathbb{N}_{odd}\\
 \frac{s}{2}&\text{if } s \in \mathbb{N}_{even} \\
\end{cases}\\
G(s) &= C^{E(s)+1}(s) \\
F(s) &= 3s + 2^{E(s)} 
\end{align}

By convention we define $G^0(s)=s,\;F^0(s)=s$. We make the following claims:

$\begin{align}
 1.& \quad \forall s \in \mathbb{N},&  2^{E(s)}G(s) = F(s) \\
 2.& \quad \forall n,s \in \mathbb{N}, &\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right) G^n(s)=F^n(s)\\ 
\end{align}$

$
\\
$

**Claim 1 Proof**
Suppose $s=2^ks_0$ where $s_0$ is odd. We have $E(s)=k$. We start as follows,

\begin{align*}
G(s) &= C^{E(s)+1}(s)          \\
G(s) &= C^{k+1}(s)             \\
G(s) &= C^{k+1}(2^ks_0)   \\
\end{align*}

since $2^ks_0$ is even until it is divided by $2$ a total number of $k$ times, we have

\begin{align}
G(s) &= C^{1}(s_0)   \\
G(s) &= 3s_0+1   
\end{align}

Hence,

\begin{align}
2^{E(s)}G(s) &= 2^{E(s)}( 3s_0+1) \\
             &= 2^k(3s_0+1)      
\end{align}

Now we calculate $F(s)$,

\begin{align*}
F(s) &=  3s+2^{E(s)} \\
     &=  3s+2^{k} \\
     &=  3(2^ks_0)+2^k      \\
     &=  2^k(3s_0+1)      \\
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have $  2^{E(s)}G(s) = F(s) $.

**A proof for claim 2 would get the points.**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Noah, thanks. It is now stated at the bottom.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: The if and only if statement stated.

Comment: @rukhin it is cumbersome to follow, however thanks to the first draft of that answer I was able to come up with something. Finishing it this weekend.

Comment: Update: so....that didn’t work. I was trying really hard to use induction. Even if it had helped, the points are offered for a solid proof. Thanks!

Comment: Your proof might be solid @rukhin, I just need more time to finish reasoning carefully through it. Also, there might be a much more concise/clearer way of writing it.

Comment: Concise in logic/meaning, not in length. Look at @JonMark's answer for example.

Comment: @ReverseFlow I just edited my answer with proof of claim 2

Comment: Are you going to give me the points? You said you give it on the last day of the bounty and there is less than three hours left

Comment: I thought I did when I chose your answer.

Comment: People can put bounties on other people's questions and only the op can give the green check mark. So the check mark doesn't give the points.

Comment: I just read the bounty guidelines. You will get the award later today, or by Monday. If you have the answer mark, the highest rated answer, and at least two upvotes, you WILL get points after the  24 hours  bounty grace period ends. Read the bounty guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{let } {x=E(s)} \text{ therefore } {\exists\space y\in\Bbb{N}\space}\text{|}{\space 2^xy=s}\text{ (This implies } y \text{ is odd).}$

$\text{Also let }{f_3(s)=3(\frac{s}{2^x})+1=(3y+1)}\text{.}$

${f_3\left(s\right)}\text{ is equivalent to using } {f_1}\text{ on } s \text{ until an odd step is applied.}$

$\text{So }$

$\exists\space p\space \text{|}\space f_1^p(s)=1\iff\exists\space q\space|\space f_3^q(s){=4\text{ [1]}}$

${f_3^q(s)=4 \iff f_3^{q-1}(s)=2^k} \text{ (for some k}{\in\Bbb{N})\space [2]}$

$\text{If we apply one step of } {f_2} \text{ on } {s} \text{ we have: }$

${f_2(s)=f_2(2^xy)}$ ${=}$ ${3\cdot 2^xy+2^x=2^x(3y+1)}$

${f_2(s)} \text{ is a power of two } {\iff (3y+1)} \text{ is a power of two.}$

$\text{Let} {f_4(s)=\frac{f_3(s)}{2^x}=3y+1}\text{.}$

$\text{So } {f_4(s)} \text{ is a power of two } {\iff f_2(s)} \text{ is a power of two.[3]}$

${f_4(s)=(3y+1)=f_3(s)} \text{ implies  that } {f^n_4(s)=f^n_3(s)}\text{.[4]}$

$\text{The logical connection between Statements [1]-[4] shows that: }$
${f_1^n(s)=1 \iff (f_2^m(s) }\text{ is a power of two for some m)}$

$\text{Recommended ordering [1][2][4][3] or [3][4][2][1]}$

**Edit to prove claim 2:**

$\text{we want to show by induction that:}$

$$\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right) G^n(s)=F^n(s)\Rightarrow \left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k}(s))} \right) G^{n+1}(s)=F^{n+1}(s)$$
$\text{(we already have the base case from claim 1)}$

$\text{I first want to prove an identity of the } F \text{ function. }(F(\frac{s}{2^c})=\frac{F(s)}{2^c})$

$\text{notice that } E(\frac{s}{2^c})=E(s)-c \text{.}$

$F(\frac{s}{2^c})=\frac{3s}{2^c}+2^{E(\frac{s}{2^c})}=\frac{3s}{2^c}+2^{E(s)-c}=\frac{3s+2^{E(s)}}{2^c}=\frac{F(s)}{2^c}$

$$\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right) G^n(s)=F^n(s)$$

$$ G^n(s)=\frac{F^n(s)}{\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)}\text{ [0]}$$

$$ G^{n+1}(s)=G\left(\frac{F^n(s)}{\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)}\right)\text{ [1]}$$

$\text{On the right side of [1] the input of G is divided by } 2^{E(G^n(s))}$

$\text{ then is multiplied by three then summed with one as shown in [2]}$

$$ G^{n+1}(s)=\frac{3F^n(s)}{\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k}(s))} \right)}+1 \text{ [2]}$$

$$ 2^{E(G^n(s))}G^{n+1}(s)=\frac{3F^n(s)}{\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)}+2^{E(G^n(s))}\text{ [3]}$$

$\text{the right side of [3] is equivalent to plugging in the right side of [0] in F}$

$\text{ as shown on the right side of [4]}$

$$ 2^{E(G^n(s))}G^{n+1}(s)=F\left(\frac{F^n(s)}{\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)}\right)\text{ [4]}$$

$\text{using the F identity}$

$$ 2^{E(G^n(s))}G^{n+1}(s)=\frac{F^{n+1}(s)}{\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)}\text{ [5]}$$

$\text{finally}$

$$\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k}(s))} \right) G^{n+1}(s)=F^{n+1}(s)$$

**Edit2 shortened proof of claim 2:**

$\text{we want to show by induction that:}$

$$\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right) G^n(s)=F^n(s)\Rightarrow \left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k}(s))} \right) G^{n+1}(s)=F^{n+1}(s)$$

$\text{(we already have the base case from claim 1.) Claim 1 also shows that:}$

$$F(z)=G(z)2^{E(z)}\text{ (for any z }\in\Bbb{N}\text{) [1]}$$

$\text{I first want to prove an identity of the } F \text{ function. }(F(s2^c)=F(s)2^c)$

$\text{notice that } E(s\cdot 2^c)=E(s)+c \text{.}$

$F(s2^c)=3s2^c+2^{E(s2^c)}=3s2^c+2^{E(s)+c}=(3s+2^{E(s)})2^c=F(s)2^c$

$$G^n(s)\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)=F^n(s)$$

$$F\left(G^n(s)\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)\right)=F^{n+1}(s)$$

$\text{By the F identity}$

$$F\left(G^n(s)\right)\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k-1}(s))} \right)=F^{n+1}(s)\text{ [2]}$$

$\text{By using [1] when } z=G^n(s),$

$\text{the } F(G^n(s))\text{ term in [2]  
can be substituted for } G^{n+1}(s)2^{E(G^n(s))}\text{.}$

$\text{Which gives the result:}$

$$G^{n+1}(s)\left( 2^{\sum_{k=1}^n E(G^{k}(s))} \right)=F^{n+1}(s)$$

Comment: $\frac{s}{2^x}=y$, so you have $f_3=3(y+1)=3y+3$ in paragraph 1

Comment: As @JonMarkPerry points out, there’s an important typo in paragraph one.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for spotting it. Let me know if anything else needs editing.

Comment: Brilliant!! So, I will wait until last day of bounty to award to the best, clearest most concise proof of Claim 2. I wished there was a way to distribute the bounty. This has been a group effort, @rukhin’s has helped me formulate things concisely. But, yes. That’s a proof.

Comment: Upon a closer look, what property allows you to "On the right side of [1] the input of G is divided by $2^{E(Gn(s))}$"?

Comment: There are typos in the proof, and one more property is needed. But, the essence of the proof is still there. :)

Comment: @ReverseFlow The sentence below [1] is supposed to describe the process of the $G$ function in the specific case of [1]. The purpose of this is to show how I am logically justified in moving from [1] to [2]. In general case the function of $G$ has three steps to go from input to the output. The first is to divide by $2^{E(x)}$. (Where $x$ is the input of $G$). The second is to multiply by three. The third is to add one. [0] shows that the input of $G$ on the right side [1] is equivalent to $G^n(s)$. So the first step of the $G$ function on the right side of [1] is to divide by $2^{E(G^n(s))}$

Comment: @ReverseFlow If you could explain where the typos are I would more than willing to fix them

Comment: That works. You use the induction hypothesis without saying so, meanie. :p What I thought was a type turns out to be unexplained magic until now. I rewrote it, but its equivalent to what you have.

Comment: @ReverseFlow do you need any more clarification on this math problem or do you think you understand enough for what you need to know? Also I think I can shorten the proof and make it more concise

Comment: That’s fine. I get it now. Concise is good. :)

Comment: @ReverseFlow I added the more concise proof

Answer (score 1):

I missed out on the bounty :( but the best and most compact proof of the equivalence of the two functions is the simple observation that $f_2(x)$ commutes with $2x$, i.e. $f_2(2x)=2f_2(x)$

Then for any sequence of divisions by $2$ denoted $2^{s_1},2^{s_2},\ldots:2^{s_n}\in\{2,4,8,16\ldots\}$, you have that $f_2^n(x)=\prod_n 2^{s_n}\times f_1^n(x)$

$\prod_n 2^{s_n}$ is clearly $2^{s_1+s_2+\ldots s_n}$

Comment: That is really good!! You did miss it. But, thank you. Slightly notation conflation with the $s_n$ used both as the powers of two, and the evaluation of 2 raised to those powers. But, i get your point.

Comment: @ReverseFlow well-spotted. Fixed.